# T9 system to numpad

Tags: python

I am trying to do a T9 System likely the ones in phones, but using the keypad instead.
I really need some advice about how to do this.

I have already found a textfile with the words that i want to use. 
I want to be able to use the number 2 button as 'abc' 3 = 'def', 4='ghi'.. etc
If anyone is boored or just could help me on the path it would be apriciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is a brute force T9 imitator:

```
import itertools 

n2l={2:'abc',3:'def',4:'ghi',5:'jkl',6:'mno',7:'pqrs',8:'tuv',9:'wxyz'}

with open('/usr/share/dict/words','r') as di:  # UNIX 250k unique word list 
    all_words={line.strip() for line in di}

def combos(*nums):
    t=[n2l[i] for i in nums]
    return tuple(''.join(t) for t in itertools.product(*(t)))

def t9(*nums):
    combo=combos(*nums)
    return sorted(word for word in all_words if word.startswith(combo))

def try_it(*nums):
    l=list(t9(*nums))
    print('  {:10} {:10,} words'.format(','.join(str(i) for i in nums),len(l)))
    if len(l)<100:
        print(nums,'yields:',l)

try_it(2)
try_it(2,3)
try_it(2,3,4)
try_it(2,3,3,4)
try_it(2,3,3,4,5)
```

Prints:

```
  2              41,618 words
  2,3             4,342 words
  2,3,4             296 words
  2,3,3,4           105 words
  2,3,3,4,5          16 words
(2, 3, 3, 4, 5) yields: ['aedile', 'aedileship', 'aedilian', 'aedilic', 'aedilitian', 
    'aedility', 'affiliable', 'affiliate', 'affiliation', 'bedikah', 'befilch', 
    'befile', 'befilleted', 'befilmed', 'befilth', 'cedilla']
```

You can see that starting with 250 thousand words (a very big set) takes 5 numbers to converge to a manageable size.

While this code is illustrative, and will get you started, you need two more things:

1. a smaller set of words ;-) and
2. a ranking of the more common words that will appear in the T9 autocompletion area of your UI. (i.e., 'affiliate' or 'affiliation' is much more likely the desired word from (2, 3, 3, 4, 5) than 'aedile' or 'befilth'. These need to be ranked somehow...)

---

**Take 2**

Here is a quick attempt at weighting. I read the same big dictionary (the common Unix 'words' file) but then weight those words with [Project Gutenberg's The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1661/pg1661.txt) You can use any good collection of text to do this.

```
from collections import Counter
import re
import itertools 

all_words=Counter()
n2l={2:'abc',3:'def',4:'ghi',5:'jkl',6:'mno',7:'pqrs',8:'tuv',9:'wxyz'}
with open('/usr/share/dict/words','r') as di:  # UNIX 250k unique word list 
     all_words.update({line.strip() for line in di if len(line) < 6}) 

with open('holmes.txt','r') as fin:   # http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1661.txt.utf-8
    for line in fin:
         all_words.update([word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',line)])

def combos(*nums):
    t=[n2l[i] for i in nums]
    return tuple(''.join(t) for t in itertools.product(*(t)))

def t9(*nums):
    combo=combos(*nums)
    c1=combos(nums[0])
    first_cut=(word for word in all_words if word.startswith(c1))
    return (word for word in first_cut if word.startswith(combo))

def try_it(*nums):
    s=set(t9(*nums))
    n=10
    print('({}) produces {:,} words. Top {}:'.format(','.join(str(i) for i in nums),
            len(s),min(n,len(s))))
    for i, word in enumerate(
          [w for w in sorted(all_words,key=all_words.get, reverse=True) if w in s],1):
        if i<=n:
            print ('\t{:2}:  "{}" -- weighted {}'.format(i, word, all_words[word]))

    print()        

try_it(2)
try_it(2,3)
try_it(2,3,4)
try_it(2,3,3,4)
try_it(6,6,8,3)   
try_it(2,3,3,4,5)
```

Prints:

```
(2) produces 2,584 words. Top 10:
     1:  "and" -- weighted 3089
     2:  "a" -- weighted 2701
     3:  "as" -- weighted 864
     4:  "at" -- weighted 785
     5:  "but" -- weighted 657
     6:  "be" -- weighted 647
     7:  "all" -- weighted 411
     8:  "been" -- weighted 394
     9:  "by" -- weighted 372
    10:  "are" -- weighted 356

(2,3) produces 261 words. Top 10:
     1:  "be" -- weighted 647
     2:  "been" -- weighted 394
     3:  "before" -- weighted 166
     4:  "after" -- weighted 99
     5:  "between" -- weighted 60
     6:  "better" -- weighted 51
     7:  "behind" -- weighted 50
     8:  "certainly" -- weighted 45
     9:  "being" -- weighted 45
    10:  "bed" -- weighted 40

(2,3,4) produces 25 words. Top 10:
     1:  "behind" -- weighted 50
     2:  "being" -- weighted 45
     3:  "began" -- weighted 25
     4:  "beg" -- weighted 13
     5:  "ceiling" -- weighted 10
     6:  "beginning" -- weighted 7
     7:  "begin" -- weighted 6
     8:  "beggar" -- weighted 6
     9:  "begging" -- weighted 4
    10:  "begun" -- weighted 4

(2,3,3,4) produces 5 words. Top 5:
     1:  "additional" -- weighted 4
     2:  "addition" -- weighted 3
     3:  "addicted" -- weighted 1
     4:  "adding" -- weighted 1
     5:  "additions" -- weighted 1

(6,6,8,3) produces 11 words. Top 10:
     1:  "note" -- weighted 38
     2:  "notes" -- weighted 9
     3:  "move" -- weighted 5
     4:  "moved" -- weighted 4
     5:  "novel" -- weighted 4
     6:  "movement" -- weighted 3
     7:  "noted" -- weighted 2
     8:  "moves" -- weighted 1
     9:  "moud" -- weighted 1
    10:  "november" -- weighted 1

(2,3,3,4,5) produces 0 words. Top 0:
```

Comment: Would this be slightly faster if you took a first cut at the set in t9? i.e., `def t9(): c1=combos(nums[0]); c2=combos(*nums); first_cut=(w for w in all_words if w.startswith(c1)); return (w for w in first_cut if w.startswith(c2))` (that may not be VALID but you get the drift...

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to generate all possible combinations of letters resulting from a given digit sequence. Note that these combinations are essentially the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of N tuples of letters, each tuple corresponding to a digit, and N being the length of the word. To get all combinations, you can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), like:

```
itertools.product(*(letters(d) for d in digits))
```

where `letters` is a function so that `letters('1')` returns `'abc'` and so on, `digits` is the digit string representing a word.
Then iterate through your word list and find a match.

Comment: I do not understand tbh what you said, I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: @AndreasRestrup Then you can start by reading a tutorial such as [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/). [so] is a site where you ask questions about [specific programming problems](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), so you are generally supposed to have tried something by the time of asking. However, I don't mind explaining if there something specific that you don't understand in the answer.

Comment: I used to work at the company that did T9 working on the data structures underlying it and they not a good exercise for someone "pretty new to programming". Take @Lev's advice and look at some simple tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<char,char[]> btnDict = new Dictionary<char,char[]>()
        {
            {'0',new char[]{'A','B','C'}},
            {'1',new char[]{'D','E','F'}},
            {'2',new char[]{'G','H','I'}},
            {'3',new char[]{'J','K','L'}},
            {'4',new char[]{'M','N','0'}},
            {'5',new char[]{'P','Q'}},
            {'6',new char[]{'R','S','T'}},
            {'7',new char[]{'U','V','W'}},
            {'8',new char[]{'X','Y','Z'}},
            {'9',new char[]{'#','@','.'}}
        };

        public void PrintT9(string input)
        {
            char[] T9Suggestion = new char[input.Length];
            FillPosition(T9Suggestion, 0, input.ToArray<char>());
        }

        void FillPosition(char[] array, int position, char[] input)
        {
            char[] alphabets = btnDict[input[position]];
            foreach (char alphabet in alphabets)
            {
                array[position] = alphabet;
                if (position == array.Length - 1)
                {
                    string s = new string(array);
                    Console.Write(s+",");
                }
                else
                {
                    FillPosition(array, position + 1, input);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

http://coding4geeks.blogspot.com/2015/01/t9-dictionary.html